# Scala/Java subdirectories with dots in names

Tags: java, scala, classloader, sbt

By some reasons I need to use long names of the packages in my project. Like:

```
com.example.foo.bar.bazz.anotherlongsubpart.andfinallytheactualpackagname
```

So considering the name convention(at least what I know about name convention in Java), I have to create appropriate directory structure replacing dots with slashes:

```
com/example/foo/bar/bazz/anotherlongsubpart/andfinallytheactualpackagname
```

As for me it looks too ugly :) So I tried instead to replace with slashes only the part of dots:

```
com.example.foo.bar.bazz.anotherlongsubpart/andfinallytheactualpackagname
```

In other words I have here one package/directory with long name "com.example.foo.bar.bazz.anotherlongsubpart" and another one with "andfinallytheactualpackagname". Is it legal to do that? I tried to compile all this stuff using Simple Build Tool, and run my unit tests on it. And it works well. As I would name it in more ordinary fashion with slashes.

So as my experiment shows it works well at least with SBT. But I'm not sure whether such practice may lead to further issues? Maybe in different environments with different kind of class loaders etc?

Comment: If you're going to do that, you might as well just put your source files directly in `src/main/scala/`.

Comment: Good idea, Christopher, thanks. Well, I use IntelliJ Idea and it marks such things as warnings. Whereas there is nothing bad with example above. It's not a big deal but I prefer to be in good relations with my IDE. :)

Comment: Alt+enter, ignore inspection. Problem solved :D

Comment: Nah, man, without inspections and other similar stuff I could use vim instead :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Scala, the directory name does not have to map to the package declared at the source file, the compiler won't enforce this in any way.

In Java, you can't do that. The source file must be at the correct directory (as dictated by the package name declared a the source file) for it to compile.

So, if you're in Scala, you can do it as much as you like, in Java, no, you can't.

Comment: My project is in Scala only. But what about the end class files packed in JARs. Will there be any penalties if I run my jar on various JVMs?

Comment: No, it won't make any difference.

Comment: The Scala compiler will place them in the proper folders inside the JAR.

Comment: Thanks Alexey, just noticed it too.

Answer (score 4):

Scala doesn't care what your directories are named, Java does. If you have Java code, follow its conventions. For Scala, do whatever you feel like (including not using package name for directories).

Answer (score 3):

I would not recommend doing that.  As discussed in the [Oracle package name documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html) Many tools that need to translate between qualified class names and directory locations will simply replace "." with file separators and your names would break that.

Comment: There are limits to which I'm willing to obey the instructions of somebody at Sun from 1995...

Comment: @ChristopherMartin This is not "instructions", this is Java rules, as much so as with any syntactical rule of the language.